# Values Importance for Binary Classifier in Python

Tags: python, statistics, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I'm creating a binary classifier in Python 3.5

So having the number of features (x1..xn) and target value y just like this:

```
x1        x2 x3  y
Monday    10 12  1
Tuesday   18 20  0
Monday    12 22  1
Wednesday 19 19  0
Thursday  10 11  1
Thursday  10 12  1
Friday    19 12  0 
Friday    18 21  0
Friday    12 10  1
```

So there is no problem for me to do the classifier (and all the needed steps as data preprocessing, cross validation and evaluation).

My question-how to estimate is there any significant variation of the y variable depending on the day of the week (Monday-Friday), column x1?

I know some technics as feature importance but using them I can only understand what exact feature (x1,x2 or x3) is the most valuable for predictor.

How can I understand the importance of distinct value within a column (x1, days of week) for target variable?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly your question , You can create that classifier with just (x1, days of week) features and compare that with your classifier , it may have good view for you to understand weights of these two features.

Comment: In this case, convert the x1 column (day of the week) into 7 columns each representing a day of the week and then do feature importance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values from x1 column could be transformed into columns with binary logic values ([0;1]) in them. Then the features importances technics could be applied.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html